# No with a interrogative intonation replacing question tags

Tags: questions, question-tags

Is there a more relaxed attitude towards using *'no?'* at the end of a sentence as an invitation for confirmation?
In English, question tags serve this purpose; e.g.

> 'John has been drinking a lot, no?'

is less common than

> 'John has been drinking a lot, hasn't he?'

When I was growing up, the textbooks I read would frown up on this and discourage it as bad form, and a result of non-native speakers carrying over the habits of their own native languages to their English speech.
Is it becoming more and more common for native speakers to replace a question-tag with a negation in this way or has it always been seen as non-standard, but acceptable in casual conversations?

Comment: A native speaker would say "John has been drinking a lot, hasn't he?", not "isn't he".

Comment: +Kate Bunting You're right, thanks. I've corrected it.

Comment: It really depends on the register in which you are speaking. (The "no form" would not be used in writing, unless it was in reported speech.) Speech is different, in that one normally thinks along as one speaks. And we also pick up cues from the people we are addressing. So if I say, for example "I have an idea that we will lose the order", and I sense a frown of disagreement on the face of my interlocutor, I might follow it with "...no?", and an interrogative sound in my voice.

Comment: Most textbooks don't describe how to speak, but rather how to write, in at least a semi-formal register.  Statements that you should "never do xyz" must be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: What about this version: 'John has been drinking a lot, yes?'